# How to add vuetify v-pagination with v-list component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add Pagination on lists which is I am getting by the v-list component and I want to use v-pagination. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't you, better could use a table with one column instead